# Protective Gloves for bmx / trials

Tags: accidents, protection, gloves

I'm just back from hospital!

I was having fun in a skatepark with my trials bike, and something quite unfortunate happened. Basically, my thumb flexed the wrong way around.

That won't stop me though, and I plan to go back as soon as the doctor allows.

But **I wish I could protect my fingers**, at least from flexing the wrong way around.

Is there any glove or bandage that could help me?

Comment: There is this thing with DH riders, that is basically a plastic protector for the whole wrist - in case of fall or impact with an obstacle. Saw it on a video once. However, I very much doubt it will be comfortable in anything else than gravity biking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a kind of injury that is common in skiing. What happens is the ski pole handle gets trapped under the thumb when falling, causing the thumb to bend the wrong way. You can find supports [such as this one](http://www.physioroom.com/product/PhysioRoom.com_Thumb_Stabiliser_Support_Splint/3080/39114.html). I can't speak for that one specifically, but if you look up "skier's thumb" on the internet you should be able to find lots of information on the injury and ways to prevent it.

Also, something like a rollerblade wrist guard might do the job, but I'm not sure how well you could grip the handlebars with something like that.

Comment: Well spotted, it's indeed the skiers thumb! Good thing is, recovery will be quick. However, as you say, there's no soldier gullet protection for this apparently... just a bit more luck, and falling better. Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 2):

A lot of motocross/motorcycle gloves have support built into the fingers to prevent excess motion in the wrong direction (like [these](http://www.motorcycle-superstore.com/35882/i/knox-biomech-hand-armor-gloves&colorid=1&sizeid=110?siteID=CSE_GBase_321818&WT.mc_ID=80003&P_ID=321818&adpos=1o4&creative=51533288573&device=c&matchtype=&network=g&gclid=CLql4Y2BycICFQmqaQodmQgAPQ)). There are a few DH mountain biking gloves that have "armor" on the fingers that restrict movement a bit. Unfortunately, with braking and tricks and steering, it's important to have a good range of motion in the hand, fingers, and wrist, so you might be doing more harm than good!

Comment: +1, pretty common in moto, but I haven't seen such gloves for pedalbikes.

Comment: I happen to have motorcycle gloves as well. Will consider!